# How to remove space in keys of a JSON object

Tags: javascript

I have an output like below:

```js
output = {
  "New Classroom": [{
    "Name": "Apple",
    "Age": "6",
    "Percentage": "24.00%"
  }, {
    "Name": "Orange",
    "Age": "5",
    "Percentage": "9.88%"
  }, {
    "Name": "Green",
    "Age": "2",
    "Percentage": "27.27%"
  }, {
    "Name": "Grey",
    "Age": "6",
    "Percentage": "12.63%"
  }]
}
```

How do I replace `New Classroom` with `NewClassroom` and the New classroom is not always a "NewClassroom".It may be different text

```
ob = JSON.parse(output);

alert(Object.keys(ob))
```

when I do this, I'm getting `Newclassroom` as the key

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the top-level property names in the object you receive, detect any with spaces, and remove the spaces. (You don't need to, they're perfectly valid property names, but you *can* if you want.)

```js
var output = { "New Classroom": [{"Name": "Apple","Age": "6","Percentage": "24.00%"},{"Name": "Orange","Age": "5","Percentage": "9.88%"},{"Name": "Green","Age": "2","Percentage": "27.27%"},{"Name": "Grey","Age": "6","Percentage": "12.63%"}]};
var name, newName;
// Loop through the property names
for (var name in output) {
  // Get the name without spaces
  newName = name.replace(/ /g, "");
  // If that's different...
  if (newName != name) {
    // Create the new property
    output[newName] = output[name];
    // Delete the old one
    delete output[name];
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

Note that using `delete` on an object can reduce the performance of subsequent property lookups. 99.99% of the time, that doesn't matter. If it matters in your case, create a *new* object rather than modifying it in place:

```js
var output = { "New Classroom": [{"Name": "Apple","Age": "6","Percentage": "24.00%"},{"Name": "Orange","Age": "5","Percentage": "9.88%"},{"Name": "Green","Age": "2","Percentage": "27.27%"},{"Name": "Grey","Age": "6","Percentage": "12.63%"}]};
var name, newName;
var newOutput = {};
// Loop through the property names
for (var name in output) {
  // Get the name without spaces
  newName = name.replace(/ /g, "");
  
  // Copy the property over
  newOutput[newName] = output[name];
}
console.log(newOutput);
```

Comment: so this won't work if `Percentage` has got some spaces ?

Comment: @Mahi: It wasn't my impression that was the question. No, it wouldn't, because we're only processing the top-level object. The same principal can, of course, be applied to the objects in the subordinate array...

Answer (score 2):

- Use `Object.keys` to get all keys of the object
- Use `String#replace` to replace character from `String`

```js
var obj = {
  "New Classroom": [{
    "Name": "Apple",
    "Age": "6",
    "Percentage": "24.00%"
  }, {
    "Name": "Orange",
    "Age": "5",
    "Percentage": "9.88%"
  }, {
    "Name": "Green",
    "Age": "2",
    "Percentage": "27.27%"
  }, {
    "Name": "Grey",
    "Age": "6",
    "Percentage": "12.63%"
  }]
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  var replaced = key.replace(' ', '');
  if (key !== replaced) {
    obj[replaced] = obj[key];
    delete obj[key];
  }
});
console.log(obj);
```

**Note:** Only single occurrence of space is considered, `RegEx` could be used if `space` occurrence is more than once!

Comment: Use regex for the replace otherwise it only replaces the first space.

Answer (score 1):

Loop in each keys of the `json`, then parse.

try regexp

```js
var word = "New Classroom"
word = word.replace(/\s/g, '');
console.log(word)
```